# Make call with twilio in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to integrate Twilio in my website for voice call.

This is the code I am using:

```
var client = twilio(config.accountSid, config.authToken);
app.post('/call', function(request, response) {
    var salesNumber = request.body.salesNumber;
    var url = 'http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml';

    var options = {
        to: request.body.phoneNumber,
        from: config.twilioNumber,
        url: url,
    };

    client.calls.create(options)
    .then((message) => {
        console.log(message.responseText);
        response.send({
        message: 'Thank you! We will be calling you shortly.',
    });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        response.status(500).send(error);
    });
});
```

By this code my call are connecting.When answering that call ,it give some static voice ('Thanks for trying our documentation. Enjoy!').And  call disconnected .Is there any way to make communication just like normal call communication between two person? 
Please guide me.
Thanks..

Comment: Hey! check your URL. I m sniffing some issue in it. This should be something like "api.twilio.com".

Comment: Please explain which URL I will use.

Comment: try click to call demo provided by Twilio.

Comment: I have try it, all things are working.But my question is that when When answering the call ,it give some static voice ('Thanks for trying our documentation. Enjoy!')..

Comment: Your code is just hitting the demo URL which shows you your basic functionality is working[as it makes a call]. for two way communication, you need to follow docs.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-make-outbound-phone-calls

Comment: I have also followed this document.Example in documents, this is using the demo URL ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

What you have implemented so far is the first half of a click to call implementation. You code takes a number and creates a call between that number and your Twilio number. This means you have one leg of a call, between a real person and Twilio.

You have identified that you are using a demo URL. This URL is key to what happens next with the call. You need to provide a URL that will direct Twilio to drive the next part of the call for you, dialling someone else.

The URL needs to return [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml) to do this. TwiML is XML that tells Twilio what to do with call. The demo URL returns some TwiML that includes [`<Say>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/say), that is responsible for reading the message out to you.

If we want to connect this call to someone else, we need to dial them. To do that with TwiML we need a URL that can return a [`<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial) element with the number you want to call. It looks like you are using express, so here's an example of using express to return TwiML to connect to another user with `<Dial>`.

```
var VoiceResponse = twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse;

app.post('/connect', function(request, response) {
  var twiml = new VoiceResponse();
  var dial = twiml.dial();
  dial.number(NUMBER_TO_CALL);
  response.set('Content-Type', 'application/xml')
  response.send(twiml.toString());
}
```

You'll need to fill in the number you want to call, where I've written `NUMBER_TO_CALL`.

With that endpoint returning TwiML, you now need to connect it to your outbound call with a URL. When the call connects with the first user, Twilio will make a request to the URL, but when you are developing locally your express application isn't available to the Internet. [I recommend](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/09/6-awesome-reasons-to-use-ngrok-when-testing-webhooks.html) setting up something like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com) which can act as a tunnel through to your local development environment. ngrok will give you a URL that points at your express app and can be used when making this call.

Take your URL and replace the demo one from your original code. And let me know how it goes.

Comment: Ok thanks @phil  for your response.I  got the solution.

Comment: But how to know that the /connect request that comes in, is the original call that was being setup? What if you want to handle two simultaneous /call's, then how to know in /connect which one is which? The parent callSid for the call in /connect is null for me...

Comment: When you create a call with the REST API, you will get a call SID back in the response. Then, when you get the webhook to the URL that you provided in the API call, there will be a `CallSid` in the request parameters. Those SIDs should match.